# finding values under list python

Tags: python, json

Below is an example of my JSON file (which is pretty huge). I need to append multiple things. For `key2`, `key3` I have appended easily since it a pretty easy thing, but when I am trying to append `value1` and `value2` from `key1`. it gives me `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`.

```
[
    {
    "key1": [
        {
            "value1": int, 
            "value2": "string", 
            "value3": "string", 
            "value4": "string", 
            "value5": "string", 
            "value6": int
        },
     ],
    "key2": some value,
    "key3": some value,
    },
],
```

Comment: i tried this.  

for d in file_variable:
        info.append(d["key1"]["value1"])

Comment: @Test [edit] the question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Keep in mind that there is a list and INSIDE that list is a dictionary....
So can't access it directly. Just to show I'll do it stepwise...

```
y = d['key1'][0]
```

Now y is a dictionary, and this is where you were going wrong.

Now you can access value1 like

```
value1 = y['value1']
```

Suppose that this is your json

```
  [
        {
        "key1": [
            {
                "value1": int, 
                "value2": "string", 
                "value3": "string", 
                "value4": "string", 
                "value5": "string", 
                "value6": int
            },
            {
                "value1":int
            }, 
         ],
        "key2": some value,
        "key3": some value,
        },
    ],
```

And d is the name of your json...
Now you want to access all the value1 from the dictionaries, 
What you'll do is

`value_1s = [k['value1'] for k in d['key1']]`

What this code is doing is iterating over the list stored in key1, whose elements are dictionaries and from each dictionary I'm getting `value1` and storing it into the new list.

So now your value_1s will have all the keys...

Comment: what if i have multiple dictionaries and need to extract values from each?

Comment: Assuming you have multiple dictionaries in the same key just iterate them using a loop and access the values...

Comment: Can anyone write in the comments why my answer is being downvoted?

Comment: that's what also i am thinking, you answer is spot on between i am trying the things but it is not working out properly. can you pls detail if possible

Comment: I edited the answer...

Comment: Thanks for the detailing.